# Stop the rotation of following JQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted  rotation (setInterval) to stop after p:last-child but I am not able to. Can anyone please help me? Main aim is to just have one rotation then stop at last child of p in div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fadein').delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);
$('#container p:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
    $('#container p:first-child').fadeOut('slow')
     .next('p').slideDown('slow')
     .end().appendTo('#container');
           },
     3000
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable to hold the timer, when you're at the last item, clear the timer.  An alternative would be to run an .each() with a delay inside.  That would allow you to run the loop only once.

```
    var all_p_elements = $('#container p');
    all_p_elements.each(function(){
       $(this).fadeout().next().slideDown().end().appendTo().delay(3000);
     });
```

Something like that, not tested...just pseudo code.

**Update:**

A little research on stackoverflow pays dividends...

Your answer is here: [How to show each div, one by one on jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173227/how-to-show-each-div-one-by-one-on-jquery)

Here is a quick example in jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/syGVW/4/

Just continue to modify it until it does all the effects you desire.

Comment: Hi - I am New to this, I tried to implement your Code ,the rotation stopped--$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.fadein').delay(4000).fadeIn(1000);

 $('#container p:gt(0)').hide();
    
        var all_p_elements = $('#container p');
        all_p_elements.each(function(){
        $(this).fadeout('slow').next('p').slideDown('slow').end().appendTo('#container').delay(3000);
               });
        
                  
});

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you really whant to do but I can suggest you to iterate by `p` `children` and  use `setTimeout()` instead `setInterval()` function, and check if element which you iterated by is `last` element, and then stop iterating..

Comment: Can you help me with the pseudo code , i am new to Jquery and CSS

Comment: @user2036121 I can help but at first post some jsFiddle with your situation. Then I try to work it out.