# Loading bootstrap columns one by one on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to load the columns one by one with gap of few seconds when the page is loaded and to make this working, following the code:

```js
setTimeout(function()
    {
       $("#box1").removeClass("noDisplay");
    },1000);

 setTimeout(function()
    {
       $("#box2").removeClass("noDisplay");
    },1200);

 setTimeout(function()
    {
       $("#box3").removeClass("noDisplay");
    },1400);
```

```css
.noDisplay{display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box1">Column 1 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box2">Column 2 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box3">Column 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I think there must be some other way to do it easily and with some effects like fade or something, can anybody please suggest?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from [How to show each div, one by one on jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173227/how-to-show-each-div-one-by-one-on-jquery)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box1">Column 1 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box2">Column 2 </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 noDisplay" id="box3">Column 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.noDisplay{display:none;}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    showDiv();
});
function showDiv() {
    if($('.noDisplay:hidden').length) {
        $('.noDisplay:hidden:first').fadeIn();
        setTimeout(showDiv, 1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tTimer, count = 0;

   tTimer = setInterval(function (){
       count++;
       $("#box" + count).removeClass("noDisplay");
       if (count >= 4) clearInterval(tTimer);
   }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use interval to do it and also mix it up with some css so here's the code:

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 3; //Number of elements
    var currentElem = 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        if(currentElem <= num) {
            $("#box"+currentElem).css('opacity','1');
            currentElem++;
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

#### CSS

```
.Lazy {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 Lazy" id="box1">Column 1 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 Lazy" id="box2">Column 2 </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 Lazy" id="box3">Column 3 </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

You can also make it more dynamic by checking existence of element with "box"+currentElem ID instead!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dispInterval = 750;
  
  $.each($('div.noDisplay'), function(key, divItem) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(divItem).fadeToggle('slow');
    }, dispInterval);
    dispInterval += dispInterval;
  });
});
```

```css
.noDisplay{display:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 noDisplay" id="box1">Column 1 </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 noDisplay" id="box2">Column 2 </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 noDisplay" id="box3">Column 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```